# IOError: [Errno 36] File name too long: while using with open

Tags: python

I am trying to read a dictionary for which i am putting a that dictionary `'cm{k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3......}'` into a json and I want to read it as a json .

so i used:

```
cm_file = json.dumps(cm, indent=4)
```

and

```
while using with open(cm_file,'r') as f:
    data=json.load(f)
data['i']=i
```

I am getting an error along with the contents of the dictionary

```
with open(cm_file,'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 36] File name too long: '{\n    "k1": "v1",\n    "k2": "v2",..........     }\n    ]\n}'
```

can some through some light

Comment: You're trying to use the json content itself as a filename.

Comment: When produced by `json.dumps()`, `cm_file` is not a file at all -- it's a string; I'd suggest giving it a name that represents (or at least avoids misrepresenting) its type to avoid confusion. You can parse it back with `json.loads()`. Beyond that, the question should probably be edited to reflect what you want to do (since a proper answer will probably involve *not using `open` at all*).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to open the file **content** that's returned by `json.dumps` instead of the file name